# Media Player seek option not working properly

Tags: c#, audio, media-player, seek

Hello fellow developers.

I made a c# player to play videos and audio. To do that I used the System.Windows.Media MediaPlayer and it works great.

Here is the problem I encountered:
In some music files (not all of them) seeking to X time or playing it from the beginning to X time will have diffrent results.
In other words, If I play the song from the beginning, after 20 seconds the singer will say "Hello" but if I use the seek function to 20 sec I will hear the singer say something else (and 2 seconds later he will say "Hello").

I had to check if its the library mistake so I opened windows media player and played the song, When I click on the progress bar to X progress or when I play from the beginning to X progress the song is at different time.
Same like the library.

I checked this with VLC and it worked perfectly.

So here is my questions to you. 
Does it mean that Media Player doesn't know how to seek this music file correctly?
Do you know how to fix this?
Should I use a different player, which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,
Encoding the audio as VBR made it happen like that.
Changing to CBR solved this.